# Dealing with performance issues when displaying a log file in browser

Tags: html, css, polymer, iron-list

I wish to display a log file in the browser. I have a server which is tailing a log and sending an array of lines down to the browser over a websocket.

The issue I am facing is the performance when it comes to displaying this log. I am doing some manipulation to pull out metadata etc but I don't think this is the issue.

I am using Polymer's iron-list which virtualises the list and manages scrolling for you, however I believe the issue is because the log lines have long words that the browser is breaking in order to layout, which in turn Polymer has to manage.

This causes both scrolling and display to lag significantly. Anyone come across this in the past and know of any solutions?

**EDIT**:

I also have items that disappear when scrolling, perhaps due to this: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/102

I am happy to use some other library here if it helps.